# About use of \usepgfplotslibrary{external} and \tikzexternalize in Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, overleaf, latexmk, tikz-external

I was reading the [`pgfplots`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) manual today, and I came across the `external` pgfplots library. It should help decrease the compilation time and avoid regenerating every `pgfplots` graphics.

We (me and two other colleagues) are currently writing an article, in the Overleaf online editor, with a plot consisting of about 3000 data entries read from an external `.csv` file. So the compilation time makes the workflow slow.

I would like to adopt this technique of "convert[ing] every `tikzpicture` environment automatically to an external graphics."

How can I tell Overleaf's servers to compile the `tex` file in the above described way?

I tried the following:

The main text is written in `main.tex`:

```
% file main.tex
\documentclass{article}
%% Font encoding and input encoding %%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol} % To write in 2 columns
%% To include figures %%
\usepackage{standalone,import,pgfplots,pdfpages,graphicx,float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

%% And here is the call to the external method
%% to reduce compilation time
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % Activated!
\begin{document}
Article text....
\begin{figure*}
    \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{./figures/plot1}
    \caption{Caption for the figure.}
    \label{fig:tikz:figure1}
\end{figure*}
Text text text.
\end{document}
```

The file `plot1.tex` compiles with no error, and therefore I am not listing its contents. I did add the two commands (`\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize`) to its preamble. It is a `standalone` document class.

Lastly, I created a `latexmkrc` file that has the following instruction:

```
$latex = 'pdftex -shell-escape main.tex %O %S';
```

(I learned about it from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions%2FCan_I_run_plain_TeX_on_Overleaf%3F#What_does_this_file_latexmkrc_actually_do%3F)). It lines up (I think) with what is written in the pgfplots manual, subsection 3.2.6 (page 23), to provide a command line switch to `pdflatex`.

And, the hierarchical file structure is the following:

```
root folder
├main.tex
└───figures
| │ plot1.tex
│ │ plot2.tex
│ │ plot3.tex
├latexmkrc
```

In case you don't know, Overleaf lets the user to select a compiler in the project's settings. I tried both its `pdfLatex` and `LaTeX` compilers to do this task, and both failed.

The error I get is

> Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape
> -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "output-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{output}\input{output}"' did NOT result in a
> usable output file 'output-figure0' (expected one of
> .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system
> calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is
> also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command
> simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'output-figure0.log'. If
> you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

Comment: Exactly as the error message says, see what's in the file `output-figure0.log` to determine what the error is.

Comment: @JohnCollins This log file is 901 lines in length, but I think that this message could be helpful: "! Package tikz Error: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image 
was EMPTY. I tried to externalize 'output-figure0', but it seems there is no su
ch image in the document!?  
   You are currently using 'mode=convert with system call'. This problem can ha
ppen if the image (or one of the images preceding it) was declared inside of a 
\label{} (i.e. in the .aux file): 'convert with system call' has no access to t
he main aux file. ...

Comment: ....    Possible solutions in this case:
   (a) Try using 'mode=list and make',
   (b) Issue the externalization command 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error
 -interaction=batchmode -jobname "output-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{out
put}\input{output}"' *manually* (also check the preceding externalized images, 
perhaps the file name sequence is not correct).
   Repeat: the resulting image was EMPTY, your attention is required .
See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help."  I am too novice in TeX to have an idea of what needs to fix.

Comment: I've just realized that the problem is that the standalone package and tikz externalization are interfering with each other.  (There are actually some symptoms of this in the `main-figure0.log` and `main.log` files.)  The solution is to invoke the standalone package with the mode=buildnew option, i.e., `\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}`.  This should accomplish what you want, by requiring standalone to do the compilation of `plot1.tex`, but only if the file has changed.

Comment: Well, that certainly works. You should write this solution as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The invocation of the standalone package needs to have the option `mode=buildnew`:

```
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
```

Without that option, standalone doesn't actually accomplish the task given in the question: (a) To compile a particular `.tex` file once to a graphics file and then to use the graphics file in the main document, and (b) only to rebuild the graphics file when the `.tex` file has changed.  By default, standalone doesn't compile the `.tex` file, but simply inputs the file and uses the result, rather than doing the separate compilation.

Worse: With the default settings, for the standalone package, the `\includestandalone` command interferes with the use of the `\tikzexternalize` command, so that when `standalone` tries to input the `.tex` file it fails, and gives the strange errors found in the question.

With hindsight one can see the symptoms in the log files.  In particular, in `main-figure0.log` there's a message that the "command '\includegraphics [width=\textwidth ]{plottry.tex}' has been optimized away." (Plus a probably non-optimal suggestion as to what to do about it.)